# "5 post awaiting review" but everything is at 0, I can't review anything

Tags: support, user-interface, review

Next to the "review" button I have a "5" icon, saying there are 5 posts awaiting review, but when I click on it and go to https://french.stackexchange.com/review there is no post to review.

It's all "0 posts", "0 questions", and "0 answers".

I just finished reviewing a bunch of post and now I can't make it go away, what do I do ? Is it the number of posts I skipped ?

I can't find information about this anywhere.

---

J'ai plus de 2000 points de réputation. Je vois un indicateur dans la barre du haut du site qui me dit « 5 messages à revoir » (“5 posts awaiting review”), mais quand je clique dessus, cela m'amène à https://french.stackexchange.com/review qui me dit qu'il n'y a rien à revoir : 0 dans toutes les catégories. Que se passe-t-il ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you have the [“moderator tools” a.k.a. “10k” privilege](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (2000 rep while the site is in beta, 10,000 (hence the nickname) on graduated sites such as ELU), the indicator in the top bar shows the total number of pending reviews. This includes review items that you aren't eligible for, either because you've already acted on that item or for some other reason (e.g. review on your own post, review of your own suggested edit on a tag wiki, etc.).

Showing the actual number of reviews you can perform was deemed too expensive for the database. So the number you get is an overapproximation and is often uselessly wrong. There have been numerous complaints and suggestions of improvements over the years. See [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it), [Wrong posts number on Review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section), [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many), …

---

Les utilisateurs qui ont le [privilège “outils de modération” (*moderation tools*, aussi surnommé “10k”)](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (2000 rep tant que le site est en bêta, 10.000 (d'où le surnom) sur les sites qui ne sont plus en bêta) voient un indicateur dans la barre en haut du site qui indique le nombre total d'éléments en revue. Ce compteur est le même pour tous le monde, il ne tient pas compte de ce que l'utilisateur peut réellement faire. Il inclut les éléments que tu ne peux pas revoir, soit parce que tu les as déjà traités, soit parce que tu n'es pas éligible (revue d'un de tes message, revue d'une proposition de modification que tu as toi-même faite sur un wiki d'étiquette, etc.).

Les développeurs de Stack Exchange considèrent que montrer le nombre d'éléments que l'utilisateur peut vraiment revoir demanderait trop de ressources au système. Du coup le nombre qui est affiché est une surapproximation et est souvent inutile. De nombreuses demandes d'amélioration ont été faites depuis que ce système existe, mais en vain. Voir [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it), [Wrong posts number on Review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section), [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many), etc.

Comment: Merci ! Ce qui m'étonnait c'est que j'avais 8 posts, j'en ai review quelques uns, puis je suis resté bloqué à 5. J'imagine que c'est ceux que j'ai passé, qui demandent toujours une vérification mais que je ne peux plus voir.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, c'est ça, parmi les revues que tu as faites juste avant de poser cette question, il y en avait 3 qui n'avait besoin que d'un participant, les 5 autres (4 maintenant) attendent d'autres participants.